# How can I tidy up a hole in a plaster ceiling rose?

Tags: lighting, ceiling

I have a pretty old plaster ceiling rose with the lighting wires coming out of a pretty ugly hole that I want to tidy up.

[image]

What are my options for neatening this up?

The area around the hole is concave and doesn't have a lot of room for maneuver.

Comment: Are you trying to eliminate or keep the lighting fixture?

Comment: Good question! I was wanting to hang a light up there somehow - just wanted to somehow neaten the hole/cables up

Comment: Is there an electrical box behind that rose (doubtful)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the *right* answer is, but I'd probably go with attaching an adhesive screen, using non-shrinking plaster/spackle over that to fill in the area, then trying to tool the surface to vaguely resemble the rest of the design. If you were trying for a museum-quality repair the answer would probably be to actually take a mold of the opposite side and use that to replicate the leaf pattern, but I couldn't advise you on how.

Fixing butchered art is never easy.

Answer (score 0):

A cable needs to terminate in a box or an approved fixture (which has the equivalent of a box built in). In your picture, the wires seem to hanging down with no such device.

You can attach a very [small box](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Legrand-Wiremold-500-and-700-Series-Solid-Base-Round-Fan-Box-V5738AF/100657460) on the surface of the ceiling.
[image: surface box round]

The cable (the outside casing including the wires) is then attached to the base plate of the box with a connector. The base plate is attached to the ceiling. The cover is then put on and the base of the light fixture is attached to the box cover.

A small amount of spackling compound can be used to fill any gaps between the box and the ceiling rose. The box and spackling can be painted to match the ceiling.

You may be able to find a fixture that has a box equivalent in its base. This would be indicated by a knockout plug that can accommodate a cable connector. For these, the cable can be run directly into the connector after it is installed in the base of the unit. The unit is then attached directly to the ceiling.

```
 Images and links are for illustration only, and not an endorsement of goods or sources.
```